# pygame collision detection not working as expected

Tags: python, pygame, frameworks, collision-detection

I am coding my own framework building upon pygame and i added some functionality for movement and collisions. The framework looks like this:

```
import pygame

def check_collisions(obj1, objects):
    collisions = []
    for obj in objects:
        if obj.colliderect(obj1):
            collisions.append(obj)
    return collisions

def blit_center(surface, object, display):
    display.blit(surface, [object.x/surface.get_width(), object.y/surface.get_height()])

class PhysicsObject(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, vel_x=0, vel_y=0):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        self.velocity = pygame.Vector2(vel_x, vel_y)
    
    def move(self, environment):
        collisions = {
            'top': False,
            'bottom': False,
            'left': False,
            'right': False,
        }

        self.x += self.velocity.x
        self.rect.x = int(self.x)
        collisions_checked = check_collisions(self.rect, environment)
        for obj in collisions_checked:
            if self.velocity.x > 0:
                self.rect.right = obj.left
                collisions['right'] = True
            elif self.velocity.x < 0:
                self.rect.left = obj.right
                collisions['left'] = True
        
        self.y += self.velocity.y
        self.rect.y = int(self.y)
        collisions_checked = check_collisions(self.rect, environment)
        for obj in collisions_checked:
            if self.velocity.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = obj.top
                collisions['bottom'] = True
            elif self.velocity.y < 0:
                self.rect.top = obj.bottom
                collisions['top'] = True
        return collisions

            

class Entity(PhysicsObject):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, vel_x=0, vel_y=0):
        super().__init__(x, y, width, height, vel_x, vel_y)
        self.surf = pygame.Surface((self.width, self.height))
        self.surf.fill('red')
        self.colorkey = (0, 0, 0)
        self.surf.set_colorkey(self.colorkey)

    def set_image(self, image):
        if image is str:
            self.surf = pygame.image.load(image)
        else:
            self.surf = image
    
    def set_color(self, color):
        self.surf.fill(color)
    
    def set_size(self, width=None, height=None):
        if width is not None:
            self.width = int(width)
        if height is not None:
            self.height = int(height)

    def display(self, display):
        display.blit(self.surf, [self.x-self.width/2, self.y-self.height/2])
```

now in my test file i wanted to test this functionality but when i move my player into the obstacle it doesnt stop. It just moves through it. why is this? and how can i fix this.

also my test script looks like this:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
from gameFrame import *

pygame.init()

display_size = [500, 500]
display = pygame.display.set_mode(display_size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = Entity(32, 32, 32, 32)
obstacle = Entity(200, 200, 200, 32)

while True: # Main gameloop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Prevent frozen program
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    display.fill([70, 120, 255]) # Make Background
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    player.velocity.xy = 0, 0
    if keys[K_w]:
        player.velocity.y = -5
    if keys[K_s]:
        player.velocity.y = 5
    if keys[K_a]:
        player.velocity.x = -5
    if keys[K_d]:
        player.velocity.x = 5

    player.display(display)
    obstacle.display(display)
    player.move([obstacle.rect])

    pygame.display.update() # Update the display
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: What are K_w, K_a, etc? I'm not familiar with the pygame key accessing. Does it come from pygame.locals or gameFrame? But in any case, star imports should be avoided. (Import only what is needed)

Comment: @JacobA they come from `pygame.locals` but, yes I agree - these could also be accesed by using `pygame.K_w`

Comment: Thank you for the advise however it is not solving the issue that i am facing.

i think the issue is coming from the move function in the Physicsobject class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not enough to constrain the position of the rectangle (`self.rect.bottom`, `self.rect.left`). If you change `self.rect.bottom` or `self.rect.left` you must set `self.x` as well, since `self.rect.x` is set again by `self.x` in the next frame:

```py
class PhysicsObject(object):
    # [...]

    def move(self, environment):
        collisions = {'top': False, 'bottom': False, 'left': False, 'right': False,}

        self.x += self.velocity.x
        self.rect.x = int(self.x)
        collisions_checked = check_collisions(self.rect, environment)
        for obj in collisions_checked:
            if self.velocity.x > 0:
                self.rect.right = obj.left
                self.x = self.rect.x                      # <---
                collisions['right'] = True
            elif self.velocity.x < 0:
                self.rect.left = obj.right
                self.x = self.rect.x                      # <---
                collisions['left'] = True
        
        self.y += self.velocity.y
        self.rect.y = int(self.y)
        collisions_checked = check_collisions(self.rect, environment)
        for obj in collisions_checked:
            if self.velocity.y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = obj.top
                self.y = self.rect.y                      # <---
                collisions['bottom'] = True
            elif self.velocity.y < 0:
                self.rect.top = obj.bottom
                self.y = self.rect.y                      # <---
                collisions['top'] = True
        return collisions
```